# How to understand the meaning of this as...as sentence seems to be self-contradictory?

Tags: meaning, idioms

This time I encountered a seemingly self-contradictory sentence from a book:

> It's easy to see that locate is **as simple as** find is **complicated**.

Apparently, **simple** and **complicated** are two words with totally opposite meanings. However, **as...as** sentence used here may imply they are ... the same? I'm confused about the usage of as...as sentence here and how to understand the true meaning. Could someone help?

Comment: *locate* is to *simple* as *find* is to *complicated*

Comment: The question calls for a clarification of a one-off expression, which does not illustrate any general feature of English language and usage.